# Using SlideOut Navigation in MonoCross iOS App

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monocross

Dillon Buchanan has a great [example for creating the a left side slide-out](http://www.dillonbuchanan.com/programming/monotouch-slide-out-navigation/) navigation in MonoTouch.

My problem is that I'm using the MonoCross and cannot figure out how to implement this. Below is a snippet from Dillon's vs my `FinishedLaunching` implementation.

**Dillon's:**

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    Menu = new SlideoutNavigationController();
    Menu.TopView = new HomeViewController();
    Menu.MenuView = new DummyController();

    window.RootViewController = Menu;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

    return true;
}
```

**Mine**

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    // create a new window instance based on the screen size
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    MXTouchContainer.Initialize(new eDash.App(), this, window);

    // Add Views
    MXTouchContainer.AddView<List<Location>>(typeof(LocationListView), ViewPerspective.Default);
    MXTouchContainer.AddView<Location>(typeof(LocationView), ViewPerspective.Default);
    MXTouchContainer.AddView<List<Engagements>>(typeof(EngagementsListView), ViewPerspective.Default);


    MXTouchContainer.Navigate(null, MXContainer.Instance.App.NavigateOnLoad);

    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BeginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications(); 
    UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor =UIColor.Black;


    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem or error message that are you getting? Can you share it or a sample code on a github gist?